# ASP.NET Boilerplate multiple databases and DbContexts

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, aspnetboilerplate

I want to connect to two databases at once using ASP.NET Boilerplate. I followed this example: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/tree/master/MultipleDbContextEfCoreDemo

The problem is that only the first context will have all the Abp tables on it. The second context is an existing database, which has none of the Abp tables on it.

When I start up the web app, I get this:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'AbpLanguages'.'
```

So obviously it is looking for Abp* tables on the second context, but they don't exist there (and they should not). So, what is the correct way to have more than one context, so that it doesn't look for Abp* tables on the second context?

## Update

I have created an example application by modifying a clean ASP.NET Boilerplate project generated from a template.

I have tested with a project generated from the template which is API-only, and there it works perfectly. But when API and frontend are combined when generating the project, I am getting these issues where the Abp* tables are looked for on additional contexts.

Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/19gj8ms0jwz500k/4.0.1.zip?dl=0
Github: https://github.com/FrikkinLazer/MultipleContext.git

Comment: The second context can be found under TwoContexts.EntityFrameworkCore -> EntityFrameworkCore -> SecondContext. I added it to github as well.

Comment: There's no `SecondDbContext`.

Comment: Its under /src/TwoContexts.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/SecondContext/Models/, and it is called TEST1Context

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```cs
> // using Abp.Zero.EntityFrameworkCore;
>
> public partial class TEST1Context : AbpZeroDbContext<Tenant, Role, User, TEST1Context>
> {
>     // ...
> }
> ```

`Abp.Zero.EntityFrameworkCore`'s [`AbpZeroDbContext`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/bc266e3503fcb2825684ec829cc356815f94f397/src/Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore/Zero/EntityFrameworkCore/AbpZeroDbContext.cs) defines the `DbSet`s for Module Zero tables.

> the second context is an existing database, that have none of the Abp tables on it.
>
> So, what is the correct way to have more than one context, so that it doesnt look for Abp* tables on the second context?

For the second context, subclass `Abp.EntityFrameworkCore`'s [`AbpDbContext`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/8c4336dd9729c499409ed32e1dcd7b2535876a5c/src/Abp.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/AbpDbContext.cs).