# Second DB Context not usable in unit tests

Tags: asp.net-boilerplate

After I managed to get multiple Database Context working in asp.net boilerplate (with some help here [ASP.NET Boilerplate multiple databases and DbContexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650555/asp-net-boilerplate-multiple-databases-and-dbcontexts)), I ran into another problem. In the unit tests, when I use one of the additional database contexts like so:

```
 using (var uow = this.UnitOfWorkManager.Begin())
 {
   var r = this.SlipLineRepository.GetAll().ToList();
 }
```

I get this error:

```
Abp.AbpException : Could not resolve DbContextOptions for SlipStreamAPI.SlipStreamDB.miSlipLiveContext, SlipStreamAPI.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
```

So my questions are:
1) Is it possible to test against in memory DB contexts, if they are the second, third, etc context?
2) If it is, what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [register DbContextOptions](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/63f6e3b6147b6df7a08b09a53dad562c57dac17c/aspnet-core/test/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Tests/DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionRegistrar.cs#L24-L32) in **ServiceCollectionRegistrar.cs**:

```cs
public static void Register(IIocManager iocManager)
{
    // ...

    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<miSlipLiveContext>();
    builder.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);

    iocManager.IocContainer.Register(
        Component
            .For<DbContextOptions<miSlipLiveContext>>()
            .Instance(builder.Options)
            .LifestyleSingleton()
    );
}
```